# Extract e-mail attachments on Unix

Tags: unix, email, shell

Do you know how to extract attachments from a raw mail message on Unix?
I want to do it from a shell script (ksh). The mail file is the raw e-mail with headers and encoded attachments.

PS: I can't use Perl.

Thx.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[mpack](http://linux.maruhn.com/sec/mpack.html) did it for me! (actually the munpack part)
Exactly what I needed: tiny standalone executable with no extra.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is to use `uudeview`. Works similar to `munpack`. Just type

`$ uudeview file.eml`

Comment: I second uudeview because in contrast to munpack it supports files containing multiple e-mails.

Answer (score 2):

A very long time ago, I used metamail for exactly this sort of thing.

see https://kb.iu.edu/d/aibt

M.

Comment: Thanks, but: metamail: Could not find end of mail headers.
I'm on an old HP-Ux B11.11 system..

Answer (score 2):

I would take a look at [MH](http://www.newt.com/faq/mh.html) and its successor, [NMH](http://www.nongnu.org/nmh/). From the FAQ:

> The MH message handling system is a
>   set of electronic mail programs   in
>   the public domain. If your computer
>   runs Unix, it can probably   run MH.
>
> The big difference between MH and
>   most other "mail user agents" is
>   that you can use MH from a Unix shell
>   prompt. In MH, each command is   a
>   separate program, and the shell is
>   used as an interpreter. So, all   the
>   power of Unix shells (pipes,
>   redirection, history, aliases, and
>   so on) works with MH--you don't have
>   to learn a new interface. Other   mail
>   agents have their own command
>   interpreter for their individual
>   mail commands (although the mush mail
>   agent simulates a Unix shell).

Comment: MH is dead! Its home is closed: http://www.ics.uci.edu/~mh/.

I couldn't even find manual pages..

Comment: I can't compile nmh on my system :'(
        cc -s -o ali ali.o aliasbr.o ../config/version.o ../config/config.o ../mts/libmts.a ../sbr/libmh.a    -lm
/usr/ccs/bin/ld: Unsatisfied symbols:
   _filbuf (first referenced in ../sbr/libmh.a(m_getfld.o)) (code)
*** Error exit code 1